# Can't write to Fat32 MicroSD disk

Tags: macos, sd-card, fat32

I have a disk, it is MicroSD and I have a macbook. I enter said disk into said Macbook and when I try to copy I get...

```
/Volumes/SDCARD/file.img: Read-only file system
```

I tried the ole......

```
sudo chmod - R 777 /Volumes/SDCARD
```

But not luck any ideas?

I also made sure the read-only switch on the adapter wasn't set

*FDisk*

```
Disk: /dev/disk2    geometry: 964/64/63 [3887104 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
*1: 0B 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [      2048 -    3885056] Win95 FAT-32
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

Comment: is it encrypted ?

Comment: Fat32 has a 4GB file-size limit. Could you be hitting this restriction?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Maybe but I would think I could still reformat or something.

Comment: @IconDaemon the SD card is only 2GBs. Disk utility won't let me format either.

Comment: find the disk identifier with `diskutil list` (assuming disk1). what's the output of `sudo fdisk /dev/disk1` ?

Comment: updated the question with info

Answer (score 1):

The SD Card is failing. Oddly enough, you can mount it as RW using a SDXC > USB adapter (don't ask my why, but it works) **[such as this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002P5VKSE)**. Once mounted, you can copy data off the card. It's not a question of a corrupted filesystem, but a physical failure of the device - for example, although you *will be able to reformat the card* when connected via this adapter, it will nevertheless revert back to read only if connected directly again; it will eventually fail completely. If citations are desired, I don't have any off-hand. My source is personal experience, multiple times over. Best of luck.

**Update (Found an old card):**

Here is one of my old, dead 8GB SD cards that is read only when connected via my SDXC port:
[image]
...And R/W when connected via my USB. 
[image]

...And finally, immediately after I took these screenshots:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try remounting the filesystem in read-write mode, using:

```
mount -o update /dev/disk2
```